# Change tables loaded in the grid with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing this for my own learning. It is not home work. All example I have found are for asp solutions.

I have a *Grid* and a *DropDownList* in a *Winform*.
The *Grid* has a *DataSet* a *BindingSource* and a *TableAdapter*.
I populate the dropdownlist with the tables in the DB as following:

```
public  void FillDropDownList(string connString)
    {
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where Table_Name like 'Table%'";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(myReader);
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
               //to be completed
            }

            radDropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
        }
    }
```

The line that loads the data in the grid is like this:

```
 this.table_xxxTableAdapter.Fill(this.xxxDataSet.Table_xxx);
```

So I suspect that with these components I would need a new dataset for each table but I do not like to do that because new tables may be created in the future.

How can I change the table loaded in the grid selecting tables from the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataSet requires that you specify the tables you may want to load at design time, but it sounds like you want to load these tables dynamically (because they may get added to the database from another source?)

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should simply do this:

Whenever the user selects a table, load the selected table using a dynamic query and re-databind the grid to it.  The code should look something like this.  **Note:** *This is untested code.*

```
protected void radDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string query = BuildQuery(radDropDownList.SelectedValue);  //Pass in the table name
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ad.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
           //TODO: Handle this exception.
        }
    }

    radGrid.DataSource = dt;
    radGrid.DataBind();
}

private string BuildQuery(string table)
{
    //TODO:  Provide your own implementation for your query.
    return string.Format(
        @"SELECT * FROM {0}", table);
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I would like to achieve. You understood correctly. Thanks a lot for your snippet. I am having errors on BuildQuery and dataAdapter even after I added the name space and the dll for System.Data.SqlClient and System.Management. I see in your code it is fine. Any hint on the possible reason? Sorry to ask, could you include the TODO part? I would really appreciate.

Comment: Because there's a million in one ways to do it, I just basically copied your code from the question with a few minor replacements.  I guess I didn't specify, but you need to provide your own implementation for the BuildQuery method and my code assumes that you are using the table name as the value as well as the text in the RadDropDownList.  If this is not the case, you may need to change that bit of code.  But, it's now updated so please let me know if you have further questions.